# Existence of an unbounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to know why a sequence that is not bounded cannot have all of its subsequences converge to the same limit. According to Lebl, a bounded sequence is convergent and converges to x if and only if every convergent subsequence converges to x. I know that convergent subsequences must be bounded... But I'm having a hard time relating subsequences to their corresponding sequences in a way that implies something meaningful about the sequences. Can anyone give me hints?

Comment: It's not clear which part you're confused about. The first sentence seems to say one thing and the rest seems to say something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outline of a proof for you to fill out:

**Theorem:** Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $x$ be a real number. Then $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ if and only if both of the following hold:

1. $(x_n)$ is bounded. That is there are $a,b \in \Bbb R$ such that for all $n\in \Bbb N$, $a\le x_n \le b$.
2. Every convergent subsequence of $(x_n)$ converges to $x$. That is, for each increasing sequence of integers $n_k$, if $(x_{n_k})$ converges, then $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $x$.

**Lemma 1:** If $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers, then $(x_n)$ is bounded.

**Proof:** Suppose $(x_n)$ converges to $x$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N>0$ such that …. In particular, letting $\epsilon = 1$ ….

**Lemma 2:** If $(x_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers converging to $x$, and $(x_{n_k})$ is *any* subsequence thereof, then $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $x$.

**Lemma 3:** If $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers, then $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

**Lemma 4:** If $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers that does not converge to $x$ then it must have a subsequence that converges in $(x,\to)$ or in $(\gets,x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume a sequence isn't bounded. You can easily have convergent subsequences. For example, take the sequence $1, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0...$, which is unbounded and has exactly one sequence that is convergent.

However, you can't have **all** of the subsequences of an unbounded sequence be convergent. For one, every sequence has itself as a subsequence. So that's one that isn't convergent. If you only want proper subsequences, let $S_n, n \in N$ be the numbers in the main sequence and make your subsequence $S' = S_2, S_3, S_4...$ Since $S_1 \notin S'$, it's a proper subsequence that is also unbounded.

Finally, we can show that there must exist subsequences that are unbounded even if you remove an **infinite** amount of terms. Since $S$ is unbounded, for every number $a > 0$ there is some $n$ st $S_n > a$. So let $\alpha(x)$ be the smallest $n$ such that $S_n > x$. Then the subsequence $S' = S_{\alpha(1)}, S_{\alpha(3)}, S_{\alpha(5)} ...$ is a proper subsequence of S and is unbounded.

Note: To make sure it's actually a real subsequence you have to modify it to $\alpha(x)$ is the smallest n such that $S_n > x$ **and** that $\alpha(n) > \alpha(n-1)$. Otherwise if S was $101, 102, 103...$ we'd get $S' = 101,101,101...$ which is not a subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a sequence $(x_n)$ that is not bounded. Remember that a sequence is bounded if you have some positive number $M$ such that $|x_n|<M$ for all $n$. The negation of this statement is as follows. For all $M>0$, there is some $n$ such that $|x_n|>M$.

Now, for each integer $k$, choose such an integer $n_k$ such that $|x_{n_k}|>k$. and consider the subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$. Clearly, this subsequence cannot converge, because its absolute value becomes arbitrarily large eventually.

To see this formally, suppose that $(x_{n_k})$ converges to some real $c$. Then, for all $\varepsilon>0$, there must exist an integer $K$ such that for all $k>K$, we have $$|x_{n_k}-c|<\varepsilon.$$ But for such values of $k$, $$k<|x_{n_k}|=|x_{n_k}-c+c|\leq|x_{n_k}-c|+|c|<\varepsilon +|c|.$$ However, $k$ must exceed $\varepsilon+|c|$ for $k$ large enough, leading to a contradiction.